# Mocking `react-dom/client` with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom

I'm looking to mock `react-dom` from within a Create React App.

With the change to the API, the import statement now looks like

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
```

And the use of the code is:

```js
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(<App />);
```

I've made a `__mocks__` folder, and if it were just `react-dom` I think the file would then be named `react-dom.js` to mock it. But I don't see any example of how to mock when our API isn't the same. The closest I've found is scoped modules, but since this isn't with `@` I don't think it follows the same rules. How can I get the mocks folder to register correctly?

I've tried making a folder called react-dom with a `client.js` file, which didnt seem to work.

I've tried explicity mocking in the test file:

```js
jest.mock('react-dom/client', () => {
  return {
    createRoot: jest.fn( () => {
      return {
        render : jest.fn()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Which I think works/is close, but then causes issues with React Testing Library. How can I correctly mock this?

I want to export a Redux store variable that lives inside the `index.js` into my tests. I run a school, so yes, we could try to move the store into its own file, but I'd like to avoid that as we'd have to alter a lot of assignments for that change. When you import from `index.js`, React-DOM is trying to actually render when we don't need, and when there is no HTML file, as it's a test.

It may be impossible to do, as react-dom is part of RTL.

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. React DOM is needed to actually render the components to elements (hence the "issues" with RTL when you do mock it out).

Comment: I appreciate the thought. The issue really is stemming from when you import part of a file, it runs that whole file. I dont need React-Dom to run. So, in this odd case, mocking it might be a solution.  

The other solution Ive found is moving the store into its own file to avoid the react-dom issue entirely, but looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mockRender = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-dom/client", () => ({ 
  createRoot: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    render: mockRender,
  }))
}));
```

in your test

```
expect(mockRender).toHaveBeenCalled();
```